# In Posgres does a varchar(n) variable accept int as a default value

Tags: postgresql

So I've been trying to install a third party software along with `CockroachDB`, a superset to `Postgres`. I should mention that the third software supports `Postgres` but does not explicitly state it supports `CockroachDB`.

During the installation it complained about the value type doesn't match the default value and looking at the SQL command (from the software vendor) that's causing the error,

```
create table llx_adherent_type_lang
(
  rowid          integer AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  fk_type        integer      DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  lang           varchar(5)   DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  label          varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  description    text,
  email          text,
  import_key varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL
)ENGINE=innodb;
```

To me the column `lang` has a type of `varchar(5)` but the default value is set to the integer `0`. Is this allowed in postgres? I would think the default value has to be of type varchar of max size of 5 characters? I tried to search for it in the docs but I didn't see any mentions to my question. `https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-character.html`.

Does anyone know if postgres allows the default variable type to be different to the defined type or is the SQL command simply invalid? Thank you.

Comment: you have some leftover mysql syntax in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough to test:

```
create table default_test(fld_1 varchar(5) default 0);
\d default_test 
  Table "public.default_test"
 Column |         Type         | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 fld_1  | character varying(5) |           |          | 0

insert into default_test values (default);
select * from default_test ;
 fld_1 
-------
 0
```

So yes the `DEFAULT` can be an integer. It will be cast to `varchar`.

Comment: it will cast on the way in, but not during a query. you will still have to select `where lang = '0'`.  `where lang = 0` will give you an error: `operator does not exist: character varying = integer`